# CLI can't access getenv

Tags: php, mysql, cron, command-line-interface

I have a website whereby the code is shared between contracted developers that I use and because I do not want to give them full access to the mysql passwords, salts, keys etc they are stored in the websites .conf file using Environment Variables:

```
SetEnv SALT ABCxyz123
SetEnv PASS XYZabc123
```

...etc etc

Using this method I'm able to get them to work on certain functions/scripts on their own environments and I can safely give them a copy (or parts of) of my websites code and/or mysql tables without them having to know any of the sensitive variables.

I have a config file that all my sites php pages use to retrieve the database password using the following:

```
$db_pass = (getenv('PASS'))or die('Could not get mysql password!');
```

The problem is now that if I create a cron job to run a php file then the CLI cannot access the getenv() so the script will not run. I don't want to have to end up running a separate config file just for these cron scripts to be able to run, as there is a lot going on in the config file including many functions.

Is there a way I can store these important variables outside of my websites code and still get the CLI to access them?

Comment: I had already seen that question, but it doesn't answer mine. My issue is that I'm setting an environment variable and PHP has no trouble accessing when running normally, but running the PHP from the CLI and it cannot see the environment variable using either getenv() or $_ENV

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system utilities to directly access the variables you need:

save to *demo.php* and *chmod +x demo.php && ./demo.php*. You could also install this as a crontab to see it working there.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

  //access the environment using system commands:
  $data = system("/usr/bin/printenv LANG") . " | " . system("/usr/bin/printenv HOME");
  file_put_contents("test.txt", $data);

  //if you want to write variables to the environment, I suggest writing them to a global
  //file such as `~/.env`.  Then in your `.bashrc` you can `source ~/.env` to load the 
  //variables you saved.  
  //If this is an acceptable solution, let me know and I'll write some shell scripts.
```

Comment: Hi Trick, if I'm using a separate PHP file to do this then could I not then simply just use a separate include file and just make sure that this include file is kept in a private folder (and read only) then my outsourced devs do not have access too? I.e. something like <?php include_once "/var/private_folder/somefile.php"?> and then store all of the individual connection settings in there? What advantage does your method has? Sorry if I'm not understanding it.

Comment: Yes, you could do that as well _(I've used it with success in the past)_.  This method is based on your original question of using environment variables to store the data.